# Is it acceptable to use ellipsis without va_*?

Tags: c++, c, standards

I often see tutorials about ellipsis with examples like this:

```
void foo(int i, ...){
    int *p = &i;
    ++p;
    //...
}
```

And I'm just wondering, is this approach correct in terms of standard? Can I use variadic args without va_* macros? Maybe some implementations store args in reversed order, or something like this.

**UPD:** "Use" = pass args portably and reliably

Comment: "Can I use variadic args without va_* macros?" - portably and reliably? No.

Comment: If by"use" you mean, *ignore*, yes. If by "use" you mean continuing to dereference `p` after that increment, *no*.

Comment: There is zero guarantee that the subsequent arguments live anywhere close to `i` in terms of memory location. The compiler is free to supply these to the function in any method it desires, and a good optimizing compiler will often use registers instead of the stack. The `int* p = &i` part probably prevents the compiler from optimizing since it will have to force that back into a *slower* memory location.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes I'm talking about using passed data, not about SFINAE

Comment: BTW, in C++, you may use variadic template instead of C-ellipsis.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Never said, or intended to be interpreted as, regarding SFINAE. What I'm said is you don't have to use variadic macros if you don't actually utilize any arguments in `...`. But if you do need to access *any* of those arguments provided through `...`, the variadic macros are the *only* way to do it.

Comment: @WhozCraig, oh, I see, I didn't get your point. But anyway my answer is "I want to use passed data".

Comment: @tadman i have to correct you a bit. Like any other function, vararg functions have ABI, and that ABI is fixed. Compiler can't decide if it wants to pass arguments through stack or registers as part of optimization (unless function was inlined, but inlining vararg functions is very tricky).

Comment: @SergeyA Interesting, though is that documented anywhere? Is it compiler specific?

Comment: @tadman this is platform-specific (and compiler-specific in a sense that they adopt the platform). With one ABI I am familiar with (AMD64) it is defined in section 3.5.7: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf

Comment: If you "often" see tutorials recommending that technique, you're either hanging out on the wrong side of the net, or you've fallen into a time warp back to the 1970s or 1980s.  `<stdarg.h>` (or `<varargs.h>` before it) has been *the* way to access variable arguments for many, many years now.

Comment: @SteveSummit, you cought me:) Sometimes. I sometimes see such tutorials:)

Comment: _is this approach correct in terms of standard?_ - No.

Comment: You should stop looking in places where such tutorials are found.  If they contain nonsense like this, it is going to be hard for you to know when they're spouting other dangerous nonsense too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Like I do :) (and well said)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mechanism for how parameters are passed to a function is very implementation specific.  They could be passed on the stack, via registers, or some other method, and the method can differ based on the datatype.

The stdarg family of functions / macros (`va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, etc.) specified in section 7.16 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) abstracts away all this and is the **only** standard compliant way of handling variable arguments lists.

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I often see tutorials about ellipsis with examples like this:

Just for absolute clarity - that example is atrocious and the tutorial best avoided.

There *are* valid uses (variadic templates and macros) of the `...` syntax which don't require using the `va_*` facilities, but none of them look like the example code you posted.